# Issues running React app on Windows environement

Tags: node.js, windows, reactjs

I have a working react app that I had hosted on a linux environment, but the client has switched their hosting provider and now I have to run the app on a Windows environment. I personally am unfamiliar with Windows and having some serious issues getting my app to work now.

After loads of debugging and testing I now can get my app to run, but when I start it, it will throw some errors which will results in a broken app in the browser.

So when I run `npm start` it will start up the app and spit out this error:

[Screenshot of the terminal error 1/2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fc08T.png)

[Screenshot of the terminal error 2/2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uFxh2.png)

It seems to spit out some complaints when using `npm run watchJS` which runs this command `babel src --watch --out-dir lib`.

I am completely lost at this point and have no idea where to go from here.

I can provide as much detail as anyone needs after looking at the question, I just don't know what else to add to this issue and don't want to fill up this question with irrelevant info.

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: It looks like a permissions issue. Try running the shell as administrator.

Comment: @Grandas Unfortunately I don't have admin access, so I just contacted the provider to try and run the command. I will let you know how it goes once they run it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is likely a bug with the version of npm you are using.

See this thread:

https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/18380

Try rolling back your version of npm to 5.3

The issue appears to be exclusive to windows with babel packages.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it helped a lot. My issues were caused by a few things such as node variables not being set, but the npm version was also an issue!